# Not receiving push notifications for created calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I create a calendar using the [`Calendars: insert`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) API.

And then creating a channel with [`Events: watch`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch).

I receive the initial `X-Goog-Resource-State: sync` but no `X-Goog-Resource-State:  exists` when I change events.

It works if I create a channel (the same way) for a calendar that I added through the web client.

**Update:**

When I came back to it this morning it worked again , I didn't change anything. Not sure what caused it.

Comment: have you tried following the full instruction in [Receiving notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#overview) ?

Comment: Yea I followed it, it also worked for calendars I created in the web client.